# While (do a jQuery) with a setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: jquery, settimeout, while-loop, setinterval

I want to do the jQuery POST every 5 seconds with different POST values from a RS.
The following code works but the function waits 5 seconds and sends all the data in the POST at once, instead of sending one POST, wait 5 sec, send next POST, wait 5 sec, etc..
I've been struggling with this for a week. I tried a setinterval and also an array, but nothing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
  <% while ((Repeat1__numRows-- != 0) && (!varmin.EOF)) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                var phoneval = "<%=(varmin.Fields.Item("phone").Value)%>" 
                var smsval = "<%=checkinactive.Fields.Item("audio").Value%>"
                setTimeout(function(){
                $.post("Trigger.aspx", { phone: phoneval,
                sms: smsval }, function(data) {
                    $("#status p").html(data);
                });
                },5000);
                return false;
        });
    </script>
    <% Repeat1__index++; varmin.MoveNext(); } %>
```

Comment: Looking at it, this should produce several `<script>` sections that all fire at once 5 seconds after the page has finished loading, all posting their values back to the server. Is that correct? Furthermore I'd like to ask what exactly you are doing with this, as this seems rather nonsensical.

Comment: have you tried using delay(). It;s available in jquery 1.5 - http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: This code will read phone numbers and SMS text from a DB and will post those to Trigger.aspx every 5 seconds. trigger.aspx sends the SMS via GSM.

Comment: Why do you have to take the long way around and send the numbers to the browser, which sends them back to the server? Can't you do a server-side script which sends messages every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work, but I'm still questioning the point of this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var values = <%=
            /** 
             * Produce JSON formatted array on the server, like:
             * [{ phone : 123456, sms : 7891011 }, { phone : ... }, ...]
             **/
         %>;

         var i = 0;
         var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (!values[i]) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                return false;
            }

            $.post("Trigger.aspx", values[i++], function (data) {
                $("#status p").html(data);
            });
         }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: tempOutput += "{\"phone\":\"" + phoneVal + "\", \"sms\":\"" + smsVal + "\"},";

Answer (score 0):

I added a JSON array and worked!

```
<%
var tempOutput = "";

while ((Repeat1__numRows-- != 0) && (!varmin.EOF)) 
{
    var phoneVal = varmin.Fields.Item("phone").Value;
    var smsVal = checkinactive.Fields.Item("audio").Value;

    tempOutput += "{\"phone\":\"" + phoneVal + "\", \"sms\":\"" + smsVal + "\"},";

    Repeat1__index++;
    varmin.MoveNext();
}

%>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(function ($) { 
        var values = output;
        .....
```